# Why does my systemd timer show in the inactive timers although I have enbled it?

Tags: linux, systemd, timer

I have created the following SystemD timer and service and enabled the timer :

```shell
$ sudo install -vpm 644 ncc-record.* /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/
'ncc-record.service' -> '/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.service'
'ncc-record.timer' -> '/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer'
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl cat ncc-record.*
# /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.service
[Unit]
Description=Record the New Creation Church Live sermon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=sebastien
Group=sebastien
#UMask=026
ExecStart=/home/sebastien/myScripts/shl/record_NCC_Live_Then_Suspend.sh

# /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer
[Unit]
Description=Trigger the service record.service
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sun *-*-* 11:29:30
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
$ sudo systemctl enable ncc-record.timer 
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/ncc-record.timer → /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/ncc-record.timer.
$
```

My timer does not show in the active timers :

```shell
$ systemctl list-timers | grep ncc
$
```

But it shows in the inactive timers with no information regarding the NEXT, LEFT, LAST and PASSED times :

```shell
$ systemctl list-timers --state=inactive | grep ncc
n/a                          n/a           n/a                          n/a           ncc-record.timer               ncc-record.service
$
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemctl enable` never immediately makes a unit active – `systemctl start` does that. This applies the same way to timers, services, and any other unit type.

The only thing that `systemctl enable` does is create symlinks according to the `[Install]` section, so that the unit would become active *on next boot* (or, rather, whenever "timers.target" is started the next time).

Use `systemctl enable --now` if you want to enable and start a unit in one command.